# 30 Hertz Video Output on 60 Hertz Monitor

Tags: laptop, video, display, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

I'm considering purchasing a laptop with two video out ports. One is HDMI at 30 hertz, the other is MiniDP at 60 hertz. I want to use both ports in a dual monitor setup. Both monitors have a 60 hertz refresh rate.

Besides for normal tasks (e.g. email, Web browsing, video watching), I develop Web applications and do bi-directional video conferencing - I share my screen and they share theirs.

Will there be any problems using a 60 hertz monitor with a 30 hertz output?

I'm thinking I could use the MiniDP monitor for applications that push frames at higher rates, and use the 30 hertz output for apps that don't - like emailing, text-editing, etc.. Does this make sense?

Any help understanding the concerns here would be appreciated.

The laptop model is the [Galago Pro](https://system76.com/laptops/galago) from System76.

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is why a DisplayPort output is limited to 30hz. Is that for a specific resolution? (4K?) The oldest DisplayPort version could support 10.8 Gbit/s, which is enough bandwidth for many resolutions at 60 hz, or even higher. Furthermore, if the GPU supports 60hz on another output, I find it unlikely that a 30hz limitation would be imposed on the DisplayPort. What laptop is this?

Comment: 30 Hz is not suitable for working with. Everything will stutter, a lot. That being said, I also very much doubt the port is limited to 30 Hz.

Comment: @Romen, I added a link to the laptop model. I contacted the company to ask about the dual monitor setup. They told me of the hertz ratings of the ports (which I had mixed up in my post (also updated)).

Comment: The HDMI is likely only limited to 30Hz if you're using it with a 4K monitor. If you aren't using a 4K monitor/TV, then you should be able to get 60Hz on 1080p and 1440p/2K.

Comment: @Jason, It really doesn't make sense that the HDMI port would only be rated for 30hz either. The *actual* rating should be a max bandwidth. *Any* display mode that runs under the rated bandwidth should work. For example, 1024x768 @ 120hz is only 2.83 Gbps, which is well under the bandwidth of HDMI 1.0 (4.9 Gbps) However 1920x1080 @ 120hz would need 7.46 Gbps and may not work over that same connector.

Comment: I wonder if System76 used an open/free HDMI implementation that has this limitation though. System76 does make a point of using open-source tech as much as possible, and HDMI is not an open or free display standard. While DisplayPort *is*.

Comment: @Romen I asked S76 about the refresh rate on resolutions other than 4k, and I'm awaiting their response. If the 30 hertz rate holds for all reasonable resolutions, would that present an issue on a 60 hertz monitor (such as flicker, trails, etc.)?

Comment: @Jason, A 60hz monitor can run *natively* at almost any refresh rate lower than 60hz. You shouldn't see any problems unless it was a very unusual refresh rate. One that the clock on the monitor's controller board couldn't directly produce. The limitation of the laptop isn't directly relevant to answering your question, but I wanted to be sure that the background information that led to this question was correct.

Comment: @Romen, I got a response from S76. They told me that the HDMI port is standard v1.4. I understand that resolutions below 2k should be able to achieve a 60 Hz refresh rate.

Comment: Even 1440p @ 60hz should be achievable with HDMI 1.4b.

Comment: @Romen, I ordered the laptop from System76 yesterday (2/20). I'll update my post after it arrives and I have a chance to check things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the HDMI port is standard v1.4, and my display resolution is below 4k there's no issue with the video output - which I understand has a 60 Hz refresh rate at 1080p.